# Include a loop in a loop in Robot Framework

Tags: loops, robotframework

I've got a problem with using a loop in another existing loop in RF 
That is just an example of what I need: I have a list of people (@{people}) and each of the people has a list of items.

I do the following:

```
:FOR | ${person} | IN @{people} 
\ | @{items}= | Create List | xpath=//div[@class='item'] 
\ | :FOR ${item} | IN @{items} 
\ | \ | ...
```

The problem is on the second :FOR I got an error 'keyword :FOR is not found'. Do I do something wrong? Or is there any other way to include a loop in another loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested loop in RobotFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544297/nested-loop-in-robotframework)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops), having nested for loops is not supported directly, but it is possible to use a user keyword inside a for loop and have another for loop there

```
*** Keywords ***
Loop over people
    :FOR  ${person}  IN  @{people} 
    \  @{items}=  Create List  xpath=//div[@class='item'] 
    \  Loop over items  @{items}

Loop over items    
    [Arguments]  @{items}
    :FOR  ${item}  IN  @{items} 
    \  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is also same as yours [Nested loop in RobotFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544297/nested-loop-in-robotframework)

sharing the same answer here as well.

**Nested for loops**

Having nested for loops is **not supported** directly, but it is possible to use a user keyword inside a for loop and have another for loop there.

```
*** Keywords ***
Handle Table
    [Arguments]    @{table}
    :FOR    ${row}    IN    @{table}
    \    Handle Row    @{row}

Handle Row
    [Arguments]    @{row}
    :FOR    ${cell}    IN    @{row}
    \    Handle Cell    ${cell}
```

Referenced from : http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a custom keyword like this: [How can I implement Robot Framework-style variables in this nestable For Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290821/how-can-i-implement-robot-framework-style-variables-in-this-nestable-for-loop?rq=1).

Please note that this does not support While loops, For loops that are not "IN RANGE", or Robot Framework-style variable construction (hence the question), but I use it all the time for my tests to avoid having a second keyword for the inner for loop. It's a lot cleaner.