# Nested loop in RobotFramework

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, nested, robotframework

I need to create a nested loop in Robot framework.
Can you please Help me do it?

```
${contents}=    Get File    ${file path}
 @{lines}=    Split to lines    ${contents}
 ${matched elements}=    Get Webelements    ${LABEL PORTAIL XPATH }
 : FOR    ${element}    IN    @{matched elements}
 \    ${text}=    Get Text    ${element}
 \    : FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
 \    Run Keyword If    '${text}' == '${line}'    Log    '${text} matched'
```

I need to have a nested loop which compares all the `${text}` with all the `@{lines}` in the file.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No nested loops in RF; that can be done only by calling a keyword with the inner loop, in the outer one.

In your particular case though, you could go without it - as you want to match the full line, that's doable through Should Contain:

```
${contents}=    Get File    ${file path}
@{lines}=    Split to lines    ${contents}
${matched elements}=    Get Webelements    ${LABEL PORTAIL XPATH }
: FOR    ${element}    IN    @{matched elements}
\  ${text}=     Get Text    ${element}
\  ${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Contain    ${lines} 
${text}
\    Run Keyword If  ${present}    Log    '${text} matched'
```

If you were going after a partial match - i.e. `${text}` to be a part of a `${lines}` member, then it wouldn't be possible like this.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the 4.0 release, Robot Framework (finally :) has support for nested for loops.
So the code in the question, with the new `FOR` syntax will be:

```
${contents}=  Get File    ${file path}
@{lines}=     Split to lines    ${contents}
${matched elements}=    Get Webelements    ${LABEL PORTAIL XPATH }
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{matched elements}
    ${text}=    Get Text    ${element}
    FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
        Run Keyword If    '${text}' == '${line}'    Log    '${text} matched'
    END
END
```

---

The 4.0 version brings also `IF/ELSE` flow control, so the inner loop can be made to break on the 1st match with it:

```
    FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
        IF    '${text}' == '${line}'
            Log    '${text} matched'
            Exit For Loop
        END
    END
```

, vs "the old way" of doing that with `Run Keyword If` and `Run Keywords:

```
    FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
        Run Keyword If    '${text}' == '${line}'    Run Keywords    Log    '${text} matched'
                                                       ...    AND   Exit For Loop
    END
```

Comment: I wonder whether Tidy will reformat `Run Keyword If` calls to the new `IF` syntax. It would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible without custom keyword containing the inner loop.
See doc: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops

I'd say that such logic should be always written using some stronger language (python, java...) and then just called from RF.

Answer (score 1):

*** Settings ***

Documentation     Learning Robot Framework

*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

Keyword with for loop

```
[Arguments]     ${x}

FOR     ${y}    IN RANGE    1   5

    Log To Console      ${x} ${y}

END
```

*** Test Cases ***

Nested for loop example

```
FOR   ${x}   IN RANGE   1   5

    Keyword with for loop       ${x}

END
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nested for loops**

Having nested for loops is **not supported** directly, but it is possible to use a user keyword inside a for loop and have another for loop there.

```
*** Keywords ***
Handle Table
    [Arguments]    @{table}
    :FOR    ${row}    IN    @{table}
    \    Handle Row    @{row}

Handle Row
    [Arguments]    @{row}
    :FOR    ${cell}    IN    @{row}
    \    Handle Cell    ${cell}
```

Referenced from : http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops